# Polymer use code from mixin in behavior

Tags: polymer-2.x

I have code in behaviors and in mixins. If I use both the mixin and the behavior in an element, the behavior can use functionality from the mixin and vice versa.
It seems a bit weird to write code that way though as you aren't making sure that the mixin is there from the behaviors' perspective, you are assuming the element includes both.
Is there a way to really include the mixin in the behavior or do I have to convert everything to Mixins and use the mixins in the mixins that need them to make sure they are always there?

Answer (score 0):

Polymer 2 Using the Polymer.MixinBehavior concepts. The mixinBehavior function also mixes in the Legacy APIs, the same as if you extended Polymer.LegacyElement. These APIs are required since since hybrid behaviors depend on them.

Example:

```
class SampleElement extends Polymer.mixinBehaviors([MyBehavior, MyBehavior2, ... ], Polymer.Element) {

  static get is() { return 'sample-element'}

  ...
}
customElements.define(SampleElement .is, sample);
```

Comment: This is about using the behaviors and mixins in an element, I was asking about using a mixin in a behavior or a behavior in a mixin